# wkhtmltopdf - Strange Behavior in multiple page because of Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf, bing-maps

I have a little problem in pdf generation... When in wkhtmltopdf i execute with an Html page that have Bing Maps, and that PDF occupies more than 1 page, the second and third page came an strange image...

Let me show the examples:

- With the Bing Maps (And with the problem...): http://pdfcast.org/download/html-with-bing-maps.pdf
- Without the Bing Maps: http://pdfcast.org/download/html-without-bing-maps.pdf

For construction of Bing Maps i use this API:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427611.aspx

```
var defaultOptions = {
    credentials: "myCredential",
    enableClickableLogo: false,
    enableSearchLogo: false,
    showDashboard: false,
    showCopyright: false,
    tileBuffer: 0
};
var mapOptions = {
    center: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
    zoom: 14,
    move: function(address) {...},
    beforeMove: function() {...}
};

var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById(divId), $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options))
```

Anyone had this problem before? Anyone knows the probable solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--disable-smart-shrinking` switch. Check the extended help on http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html